# How to search for an app in system apps using futter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am trying to create a flutter get the list of apps starting with "L" that are installed on my phone. I have used installed_apps plugin .But is just displaying all the apps present in phone . I only want apps that are installed with name "L" .How do I achieve this ?

Comment: if you have a`List` with all the apps then use: `allApps.where((app) => ....)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
List<AppInfo> apps = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps();
List<AppInfo> list = [];
for (var element in apps) {
    if (element.name?.startsWith("L") == true) {
        list.add(element);    
        print("apps===========>${element.name}");
    }
}
```